# Why BuddyPress fields not saving?

Tags: php, buddypress

I have a Wordpress+BuddyPress site.  I added some extra fields in user profile. 
When i registering user i fill all fields on register form. After i do  redirection in user profile:

```
function auto_login_new_user( $user_id ) {

    wp_set_current_user($user_id);
    wp_set_auth_cookie($user_id);
            global $current_user;
            get_currentuserinfo();

    wp_redirect( home_url() . '/members/' . $current_user->user_login . '/profile/edit/group/1/' );
    exit();
}
add_action( 'user_register', 'auto_login_new_user' ); 
?>
```

And see that BuddyPress's fields is empty. Only default wordpress fields filled.
If i not do redirecting (i mean after registretion use a actiovation email to activate user) all fields in user profile are filling.
Any advises?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `user_register` hook probably fires too early.

Try:

```
add_action( 'bp_core_signup_user', 'auto_login_new_user', 100, 1 );
```

`$user_id` is passed by the `bp_core_signup_user` hook.